# Let bash script run all the time but be abortable

Tags: bash

I have a bash script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
startsomeservice &
echo $! > service.pid

while true; do
    # dosomething in repeat all the time here
    foo bar
    sleep 5
done

# cleanup stuff on abort here
rm tmpfiles
kill $(cat service.pid)
```

the problem of this script is, that i cant abort it. If i press ctrl+c i just go into the next loop...
Is it possible to run a script like this but to have it abortable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are executing the script with Bash, you can do the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

startsomeservice &
echo $! > service.pid

finish()
{
    rm tmpfiles
    kill $(cat service.pid)
    exit
}
trap finish SIGINT

while :; do
    foo bar
    sleep 5
done
```

Please note that this behaviour is Bash specific, if you run it with Dash, for instance, you will see two differences:

1. You cannot capture `SIGINT`
2. The interrupt signal will break the shell loop.

Note also that you will break a shell loop with a single `C-c` when you execute the loop directly from an interactive prompt, even if you're running Bash.  See [this detailed discussion](http://www.cons.org/cracauer/sigint.html) about `SIGINT` handling from shells.

Answer (score 2):

The following bash script will keep running until it receives a kill signal. The trap command is responsible for handling the SIGINT.

```
#!/bin/bash

keepgoing=1
trap '{ echo "sigint"; keepgoing=0; }' SIGINT

while (( keepgoing )); do
    echo "sleeping"
    sleep 5
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use:

```
tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log & wait ${!}
```

at the end of the script, I think sleep cause to delay signals handling, but this line will response immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You can also accomplish the task by something simple like this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

startsomeservice &

read # wait for user input

finish
```